# Count Duplicates and Create Array with Grouped Items | PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have following array.

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Cars"]=>
    string(5) "Volvo"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Cars"]=>
    string(4) "Fiat"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Cars"]=>
    string(5) "Volvo"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Cars"]=>
    string(8) "Mercedes"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Cars"]=>
    string(5) "Volvo"
  }
```

I need to count all Duplicates and create a new array where i have the name of each group and the number how many duplicates there are. Could someone help me with a simple solution?

Comment: Have you made any attempts of solving this yourself?

Comment: SO is not a coding service - what have you tried?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We can _help_, after you have shown us what you have tried already, and properly described what your issues with that were. We are not here to provide copy&paste-ready solutions for people who haven’t even lifted a finger yet though.

Comment: Ive got my sql-result where i loop through to create the array. My plan was to create a multiple array with the name and the total number (count) of that name. This did not worked how i planend it so i started over

Comment: Hint: take a look at [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`array_count_values`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: There is only one group "Cars". It's ambigous how multiple groups would be organized.

Comment: @StevenStevensonson "This did not worked how i planend it"  You should include your attempt in the question, along with the result and what debugging you already did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all values of `Cars`with `array_column()`, and count their values with `array_count_values()`.

```
$array = array(
    ['Cars' => 'Volvo'],
    ['Cars' => 'Fiat'],
    ['Cars' => 'Volvo'],
    ['Cars' => 'Mercedes'],
    ['Cars' => 'Volvo'],
    );

print_r(array_count_values(array_column($array, "Cars")));
```

Outputs

```
Array (
    [Volvo] => 3
    [Fiat] => 1
    [Mercedes] => 1
)
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/1jhmh